# Is it possible to use a trigger on a table only on executed queries through Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger on a table that logs user activity to an audit table. This has proven useful, but I have not found a way to differentiate between queries executed by my applications (ASP.NET) and those executed through Management Studio.

I have been planning to make sure to run an insert query instead on the audit table whenever my applications attempt to execute any stored procedures on my database, but I realise that the trigger will fire anyway.

Is there a way of limiting the trigger to only work when a query is executed by a user of SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), or will the trigger always fire, and as such I should reconsider how I log my user's activity?

Just as a post script, I cannot utilise the auditing tools that SSMS usually allows, as I am hosting my databases on an Amazon RDS instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Mehdi Lotfi's solution, but it appears that Amazon RDS will only allow certain user levels to use this trigger.

I could mess around for a while to allow greater permissions for the executing user, but at the moment I am reluctant to do so.

Instead however, I used `APP_Name()` to determine my application name, set in my `web.config` file as part of my ASP.Net application, and then proceeded with the trigger only if the `APP_Name()` was equal to `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query`.

For example:

```
DECLARE @CurrentApp varchar(128)= APP_NAME()

--Table to audit
SELECT @TableName = 'TableName'

-- Check app name
IF @CurrentApp = 'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio : Query'
    BEGIN
        -- ...Continue with trigger
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have DDL Trigger for logon in order to control users and AAP_Name() of each user.
Following query is a sample code of DDL Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ddl_login_Audit] ON ALL SERVER 
 FOR LOGON AS 
 begin
     DECLARE @LogonTriggerData xml,
    @HostName varchar(500),
    @AppName varchar(500)

    SET @LogonTriggerData = eventdata()
    SET @HostName = HOST_NAME()
    SET @AppName = APP_NAME()

    IF (@APPName = 'Your application name') BEGIN
       ROLLBACK 
    End     
 END

GO
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, so if I have logged on to perform a query through my application, the event data is rolled back? Is that correct? Also, could I use (@APPName <> 'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query')?

Comment: You can use each condition. But if use @app_name<>'microsoft sql server management studio', can't use ssma. In order to use ssms sfter create your trigger must be use sqlcmd with -A parameter and disable created trigger.